# algorithm complexity analysis using recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm learning an algorithm, the algorithm takes as input a graph of n vertices, and recurse on some subgraphs.

the complexity analysis done by the author is based on using recurrent formula.

the equation $T(n) = T(n - 3) + 2T(n - 4) + 4T(n - 6)$ was produced by reviewing the possible recursive calls.

the author says that by solving this recurrence, the unique real positive root of the polynomial $x^6=x^3+2x^2+4$ is approximately $1.51433$.

So the complexity of the algorithm is $O(1.51433^n)$.

My question is how we can produce the equation from the recurrence formula.

Comment: That reasoning is based on the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence.  I'd suggest reading up on that if you'd like to know why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume I would like to look for the solutions to the recurrence $T_n$ of the form $T_n = x^n$ for some $x \ne 0$. Plugging that into the recurrence, you get
$$
x^n = x^{n-3} + 2x^{n-4} + 4x^{n-6}
$$
and now cancel $x^{n-6}$ from both sides, yielding your polynomial.

---

Indeed, the resulting polynomial $x^6-x^3-2x^2-4$ has one positive root $r \approx 1.51432$ (as you can see on the [Wolfram Alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E6-x%5E3-2x%5E2-4%5D), so more accurately one would say that
$$
T(n) = \Theta(r^n).
$$

Comment: This question essentially asks *why* the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a recurrence yield the complexity.  Your answer does not address this.

Comment: @Qudit No. The question is **how we can produce the equation from the recurrence formula**, not what you wrote.